# Get multiple inputs in an array

Tags: c++, arrays, names

For this code, I have the user input however many students' he/she wants then asks them to enter their names and test scores.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
int count = 0, students, names, scores;

//Ask for number of students
cout << "How many students are there?" << endl;
cin >> students;

//Loop
for (count = 0; count < students; count++)
{
    cout << "What are their names?" << endl;
    cin >> names;

    cout << "What are their scores?" << endl;
    cin >> scores;
}
```

I know there are many errors with this code, but my main objective is how to get the names and the scores into a parallel array. Thank you!

Comment: Use a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: Use pencil and paper.

Answer (score 1):

You would throw everything in a while loop, and then break it when the user wants to quit. But how do you know when the user wants to quit? For something like grabbing names and ages, it could be when the user enters "-1" for the name, which would look like:

```
std::vector<std::string> names;
std::vector<int> ages;
while(true) {
    std::string name;
    int age;

    std::cin >> name;
    if(name == "-1") break;
    std::cin >> age;

    names.push_back(name);
    ages.push_back(age);
}
```

Comment: I.... don't think that code works.  If the user presses enter without typing, `cin >> name` will continue to wait for a valid character.  (HOwever, as far as _theory_ goes, this is just about perfect)

Comment: This looks good, but I'm not too sure how to use vectors. My headings are only #include <iostream> using namespace std;. I'm a pretty basic coder, only have 5 weeks of experiece lol :P

Comment: @Mooing Duck fair point, I should change it to '-1' for the null input. Talk about a brain fart...Cathie, look up a tutorial, they'll take you maybe a few hours to get the hang of (if that), and they're indispensable for this kind of user input programming.

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable to store answer from user. Work in a loop. Ask input from user as answer in every loop. Put the condition to check the choice of user. 
**For example:**

```
int x = 1;//to store answer of user
int age;
do{
cout<<"Enter the age";
cin>>age;
//similarly for name

cout<<"You want to do again (1/0)?";
cin>>x;//if user inputs 1 then continues doing thing else breaks
}while(x==1);
```

This program continues till the user answers 1(and breaks for other values, may be 0).

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: You don't cover how to store the multiple inputs.

Answer (score 0):

your this function:

```
for (count = 0; count < students; count++)
{
    cout << "What are their names?" << endl;
    cin >> names;

    cout << "What are their scores?" << endl;
    cin >> scores;
}
```

can be:

```
vector<std::string> name_list(students);
vector<int> marks_list(students);
for (count = 0; count < students; count++)
{
    cin >> name_list[count]>>marks_list[count];
}
```